# jquery to prototype, ajax and slide

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs, slide

i am moving from jquery to prototype because of compatibility issue with IE6. basically, i have a multiple submits in one page and i want to submit the form via ajax and return the result to associated div of each form.

this is what i have used in jquery for multiple submit

i am getting value of submit id and using that for div value.

$(".button").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var Id = element.attr("id");

```
    var dataString = $("#UpdateBond"+Id).serialize();   

    //alert (dataString); return false;

    $("#flash"+Id).show();
    $("#flash"+Id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> updating.....');

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index2.cgi",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(html) {
    $('#flash'+Id).html(html);
  }
 });
return false;
});
```

another issue is slider. IE6 doesn't support jquery slider so i am kinda in dilemma. i was wondering if there is similar stuff in prototype. i am trying to learn prototype now.

Comment: Have you tried asking for help on SO with your jQuery compatibility problems? I have never run into a problem using jQuery + IE6. Seems rather drastic to move to `prototype` because of a bug that might be easy to fix.

Comment: Agreed with @dcneiner. jQuery tends to work just fine with IE6.

Comment: jquery slideToggle is acting weird in IE6. i have researched in web if i am the only one experiencing that problem but there are lots of people having same problem. i am not sure if that has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say IE6 is really, really not worth changing technologies any more. I'm all for downward compatibility and supporting older systems but you have to draw a line somewhere. My 2 cents.

Comment: IE6 is something i am stuck with right now because IE6 is standard web browser in the company i am working. plus jquery is not supported here. i was thinking of convincing upper management to support it but due to IE6 incompatibility issue, now i am planning to move to prototype because prototype is supported here. 

jquery is a such an easy framework to work with and it sucks to move away from it.

Comment: I see. Well then the only thing that comes to mind is to give them a estimate of how long this move is going to take, and what it is going to cost them.

Comment: Oh and wouldn't it be less hassle to rebuild the slider to work in IE6?

Comment: i have fixed the slider now. Thanks

Comment: IE6 may be dying out in the west, but in Russia I saw nothing else. Just beware that by ecluding IE6, you exclude many visitors from poor countries.

Comment: But why? Installing IE7 is free, and hardly more resource consuming than IE6. I am very much for designing sites so they can be accessed from anywhere, and I'm the first one to put in unpaid time to make sure they can , but *IE6*? Is there a special reason I don't see? Bandwidth issues? Specialties in Windows editions?